# Can the Repast agent table be called from user code?

Tags: java, repast-simphony

In Repast Simphony, one can view a table of all agents in a simulation (per tick) from the runtime environment. Is there a simple way to save the table or the data from the runtime environment? Or do I need to write a code to replicate outputs like what the tables shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the agent table toolbar there is a disk icon that will save the table to an Excel file.  It is also possible to programmatically generate a table and save it to file using the following example code:

```
public void log(){
    double tick = RunEnvironment.getInstance().getCurrentSchedule().getTickCount();
    Context context = RunState.getInstance().getMasterContext();

    Map<String,TableModel> models = new HashMap<String,TableModel>();

    // Create a tab panel for each agent layer
    for (Object agentType : context.getAgentTypes()){
        Class agentClass = (Class)agentType;

        JPanel agentPanel = AgentTableFactory.createAgentTablePanel(context.getAgentLayer(agentClass), agentClass.getSimpleName());

        if (agentPanel instanceof TablePanel){
            TableModel model = ((TablePanel)agentPanel).getTable().getModel();
            models.put(agentClass.getSimpleName(), model);

        }
    }

    SpreadsheetUtils.saveTablesAsExcel(models, new File("out-"+tick+".xlsx"));
}
```

Note however this would be extremely inefficient if called frequently so I would not recommend using this to log every tick.